# If you have 2 computers on a wifi repeater, does the signal go through the main router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have pretty decent knowledge of networking but have this question.

Say I have 2 computers both connected to a wifi repeater named A and B.  If A connects to B (VNC, RDP, whatever), do the packets have to flow through the main wifi router?

In other words is it:
Scenario 1: Packet flows from A to repeater to main router to B

**Or**

Scenario 2: Packet flows from A to repeater directly to B

Comment: A repeater is a fully functional wireless access point. That being said, hacks are often involved.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is **no** it doesn't flow to the main router.

Scenario-2 would be correct.

Assuming that this repeater is one radio, 50% of air time is spent as a client to the first router, and 50% is spent acting as a Access Point to it's local clients.

When in access mode, as long as both clients are infact connected to the repeater. Computer A & B should be passing traffic through the repeater interface. (Not traversing the main router)

Comment: Interesting thanks.  I was asking for my own setup which uses Merlin AsusWRT with the second router in repeater mode.  Here, the main router acts as the DHCP server and both are on the same subnet 192.168.1.x.  I thought about it mentally if these were just plain ethernet devices, the repeater switch *should* route from port 1 to port 2 through its own backplane without going back to the main switch.

Comment: The answer remains the same. Regards,

Comment: Thanks!  I have the 5ghz radio doing the backhaul to the main router and then using 2.4ghz for clients.

Comment: The performance is leaps and bounds better when you repeat this way. It doesn't suffer from the split air times issues that happen from one radio.